# После закрытия окна с графиком, закрывается главное окно

Tags: java, javafx, диаграммы

Пишу приложение на java, использую framework javafx. Программа получает данные и я рисую по ним график.

```
XYChart chart = new XYChartBuilder().width(1200).height(800).theme(Styler.ChartTheme.GGPlot2)
                    .title("Signal").xAxisTitle("Time").yAxisTitle("Signal").build();
chart.getStyler().setPlotGridLinesVisible(false);
chart.getStyler().setXAxisTickMarkSpacingHint(10);
XYSeries series = chart.addSeries("f(t)",time,amplitude);
series.setMarker(SeriesMarkers.NONE);
series.setLineWidth(0.1f);
new SwingWrapper(chart).displayChart();
```

Открывается окно с графиком и если его закрыть, закрывается и программа. Как сделать, чтобы программа не завершалась после закрытия графика?

Comment: Мне кажется проблема не в этой части кода, а в том месте где открывается новая форма. Убедись, что создаешь модальную форму.

Comment: ну она тут и открывается, display chart.

Comment: А зачем вам `swing`, если используете `javafx`?

Answer (score 0):

Это поведение по умолчанию, что бы изменить его добавьте вот это

```
JFrame frame  = new SwingWrapper(chart).displayChart();
frame.getDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.HIDE_ON_CLOSE); // или DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE
```